# Is there any better way to run batch process in JAVA than quartz

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, batch-processing

I use quartz to run batch process in java, but it is kind of complicated, So is there any other thing which we can use?

Comment: In distributed environment ?

Comment: [Something like this?](https://www.google.de/search?q=java+batch+processing) I.e.: What makes Quartz so complicated and what would you define as "better way"?

Comment: IMHO, Quartz is good for scheduling not batch processing. You may prefer spring-batch for processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search for a holistic approach in defining, scheduling and executing batch jobs, the [JSR 352: Batch Applications for the Java Platform](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=352) should provide you with everything you need. The JSR 352

> specifies a programming model for batch applications and a runtime for scheduling and executing jobs.

There are different implementations, which can be run inside an Application Server or standalone:

- [jbatch](https://java.net/projects/jbatch/): reference implementation for JSR 352
- [jberet](https://github.com/jberet): comes with various usage examples
- [Apache BatchEE](http://batchee.incubator.apache.org/): fork from jbatch with enhancements for Enterprise use

As mentioned by [bhdrkn in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32254705/is-there-any-better-way-to-run-batch-process-in-java-than-quartz#comment52390307_32254705) an alternative to the JSR 352 is [Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start build.bat");
```

Best Regards

Comment: You should explain what your solution does, rather than just posting it.